# Cannot proceed Sharepoint 2013 installation

Tags: sharepoint-server

After a clean Windows 2012 installation, I ran Sharepoint 2013 prerequisites installer and it downloaded and installed all things necessary for Sharepoint Server.
[image]

After that I clicked Install Sharepoint Server. Then it gave me a link that should install additional features.

[image]

[image]

I opened that link and looked them over. Everything quite well.

But I need a quick answer because you may know or have installed it.

What other optional, as it says, features do I have to look for ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like .Net framework 4.5 is not properly installed( i assume you install it via pre-req tool). Try to download the .net 4.5 directly from site http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=250950 and install it.

You have to Uninstall the current installed .net framwork then reboot the server and then install again.

Comment: I can't uninstall it. Because I don't see it in the list of installed programs. I download full offline standalone installer but not success. http://s17.postimg.org/5ntlgvvof/image.png